# test the best intervention dosage meta-

Tags: meta-analysis, meta-regression

I am conducting a meta-analysis that examines the effectiveness of a child abuse intervention. I have conducted meta-regression to examine how many sessions (intervention dosage) lead to the maximum program effectiveness, the results are consistent with previous findings (three or more sessions work the best). It remains unclear, however, as to how many sessions exactly work best. As a result, I would like to further explore this issue. My supervisor suggested that I should conduct a "sensitivity analysis" where I categorize sessions into "3 or more", "4 or more", etc to see what the results say. However, I am not really clear about this method. Does it mean that I will need to run multiple sets of meta-regression where I code these studies in to multiple groups for multiple times? Or is there a shortcut (I believe so)? Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

If you have number of sessions as an integer then you have presumably used it as a moderator in your meta-regression. If you believe that it has a U-shaped relationship with the estimated effect then you need to add it as a quadratic term as well as linear. You then have an equation of the form $y = ax^2 + bx + c$ which by differentiated has its maximum at $2a + b$. Note that you must include the linear term as otherwise you are forcing the maximum to be at zero sessions.